# SQL Server Query to Transform a poorly collected date into a usable date to analyse age

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, date

I have a date field called `BIRTH_DAT` and the date of births have been recorded like this:

`YYYMMDD`, where the second number of the year is missing.

So an example would be a date of birth of `4th March 1978` would appear in this field as: `1780304`

The rule in this field is that if it begins with a '1' then the date is in the 1900s, if it begins with a '2' then the date is in the 2000s

So what I want to do is to create another column that shows the correctly written version of the date so I can calculate age from it.

e.g

- Column 1 is called `BIRTH_DAT` and has values:
  1801204, 1601228, 1980803 ...
- Column 2 is a new column called `PROPER_DOB` and has values:
  19801204, 19601228, 19980803 ...

How do I go about this?

Comment: If you're going through the trouble of fixing the poorly formatted data (which is great!), why not actually use the *proper* `DATE` datatype?

Comment: Hint: You will need `CASE` clause and `SUBSTRING()` function.

Answer (score 1):

***Original answer - post was tagged `MySQL`*:**

Using `CASE` expression and operating on a string with `left`, `substring` and `concat` functions will get you derired result. Based on first character we're replacing:

- `1` with `19`
- `2` with `20`

and for any other case when first letter is not in `(1,2)` we're printing `unsupported date format`:

```
select
  birth_dat,
  case 
    when left(birth_dat,1) = '1' then concat('19', substring(birth_dat from 2))
    when left(birth_dat,1) = '2' then concat('20', substring(birth_dat from 2))
    else 'unsupported date format'
    end AS proper_dob
from yourtable
```

As @Siyual and @JanDoggen suggested, the right format for your column should be `DATE` which you could achieve by converting the string using specified format with `str_to_date` function like that:

```
select
  birth_dat,
  case 
    when left(birth_dat,1) = '1' then str_to_date(concat('19', substring(birth_dat from 2)), '%Y%m%d')
    when left(birth_dat,1) = '2' then str_to_date(concat('20', substring(birth_dat from 2)), '%Y%m%d')
    else 'unsupported date format'
    end AS proper_dob
from yourtable
```

Live example for both queries: <kbd>[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9762/4)</kbd>

***It turns out that OP is using `SQL Server`, so here's the edited answer:***

Use [`CAST / CONVERT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.90).aspx) to achieve the same thing since there is not `str_to_date` function in SQL Server.

Comment: This would be a good first step to check if the conversion is going to work, (and let him clean up invalid `birth_dat` date first) but the OP wants to have this put into a new column (and as Siyual commented) **that should be of type DATE**.

Comment: @JanDoggen thanks for your input, I've edited my answer to provide more insight on the matter.

Comment: Hi @Kamil-G - I'm getting 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from' error (line 4 - so the first concat line)

Comment: @sseager I've provided an SQL fiddle - it all works fine. Is there a chance you aren't using MySQL as you have defined?

Comment: I've also tried adjusting the query to show start position and number of characters, but then the error is 'STR_TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name

Comment: @kamil-g - apologies for I sound as thought I don't know what I'm doing (which is true however).  How do I know if I am/am not using MySQL? I'm just writing queries in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: I didn't realise SQL varied across applications :-(

Comment: ANSI SQL does not vary, but different [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) have their specific functions and ways of implementing and extending standard SQL. You're using SQL Server then . . .

Comment: Yes, I'm using SQL Server 2008 - guessing this is why the str_to_date doesn't work then

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>[`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx)</kbd> for inserting string in the another string value

```
SELECT *,
       YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) AS Age,
       CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) < 19 THEN '0-19y' ELSE '20y+' END AS AGE_GROUP
FROM(
    SELECT BIRTH_DAT, 
          CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('1',BIRTH_DAT) = 1 THEN STUFF(CAST(BIRTH_DAT AS VARCHAR(30)),2,0,'9') 
          WHEN CHARINDEX('2',BIRTH_DAT) = 1 THEN STUFF(CAST(BIRTH_DAT AS VARCHAR(30)),2,0,'0') 
          END AS PROPER_DATE
    FROM my_table 
)M
```

Comment: is it possible to now group my ages? e.g. if age between 0 and 19 then '0-19y' else '20y+'?

Comment: One new column called 'AGE_GROUP' which puts each singular age (that we've calculated from our reformatted date field) into an age group

Comment: Ok, so one last request - how do I now count the number of distinct IDs (this ID field is called PERSON_REF) for each of the calculated age groups?  I'm clearly not putting it in the right place in the query as I keep getting errors.

Comment: Do you looking for group wise count of id where group can be '0-19y' and '20y+' ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) AS Age, 
CASE 
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) < 5 THEN '0-5Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5-9Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 14 THEN '10-14Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN '15-19Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) >= 20 THEN '20+Y'
ELSE 'NK'
END AS AGE_GROUP,
COUNT(*)
FROM(
SELECT BIRTH_DAT 
,SEX
,CASE 
WHEN CHARINDEX('1',BIRTH_DAT) = 1 THEN STUFF(CAST(BIRTH_DAT AS VARCHAR(10)),2,0,'9') 
WHEN CHARINDEX('2',BIRTH_DAT) = 1 THEN STUFF(CAST(BIRTH_DAT AS VARCHAR(10)),2,0,'0') 
END AS PROPER_DATE
FROM mytable
)M
GROUP BY (CASE 
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) < 5 THEN '0-5Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5-9Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 10 AND 14 THEN '10-14Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) BETWEEN 15 AND 19 THEN '15-19Y'
WHEN YEAR(GETDATE())-YEAR(PROPER_DATE) >= 20 THEN '20+Y'
ELSE 'NK'
END
```

Comment: I've changed my groups as you can see